# reCAPTCHA v3 calling API continuously

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

[image]

As you can see in the Network Tab API keeps getting called. I am using react-google-recaptcha-v3

```
<GoogleReCaptchaProvider
        reCaptchaKey={CAPCHA_SITE_KEY as string}
        language="en"
        useRecaptchaNet={false} // Optional boolean value
        useEnterprise={false} // Optional boolean value
        scriptProps={{
          async: false, // Optional, default to false
          defer: false, // Optional, default to false
          appendTo: 'head', // Optional, default to "head", can be "head" or "body"
          nonce: undefined, // Optional, default undefined
        }}
>
```

I have wrapped my component with this:

```
<GoogleReCaptcha onVerify={handleVerify} />
```

And this is how I called it.

How do I stop the continuous API call?

---